# Alternatives to HTML5 Audio that play well with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, audio, meteor, html5-audio

I'm having issues with source updating on HTML5 audio in Meteor and am wondering if there are any other audio solutions that are simple and integrate well with the reactivity of Meteor?

Comment: Are you referring to the audio element or the web audio API...or both ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what kinw of problems you have, I'm using this, which works just fine:

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
audio.play();
```

Alternatively have a look at:

- http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ or
- http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library

Comment: There are problems if your website needs to play for instance *.ogg file. "HTML Audio" is not supported by Safari and IE

Answer (score 0):

Here is [buzz](https://github.com/brentjanderson/meteor-buzz) for meteor.
I'm using it.